# Select some rows of table, based in some values

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have this table:

[image]

And I would like to have this results:

[image]

So I did this code:

```
table_1=open(name_table,'r')
results=[]
for seq_id in table_1:
    seq_id=seq_id.strip()
    seq_id_1=seq_id.split('\t')
    results.append(seq_id_1)
results

dictionary={x: [v[1:] for v in results if v[0] == x] for x in set(y[0] for y in results)}
for items_file_key,items_file_value in dictionary.items():
    percentage = float(items_file_value[0][1])
    for value_1 in items_file_value:
        values_to_use=value_1[1] + ', ' + value_1[11]
        curValue = float(value_1[1])
        if  curValue >= percentage-0.05 or curValue <= percentage-0.05:
            write_to = values_to_use
            dictionary[items_file_key] = write_to
```

But with this dictionary, I only get the first values of the entries, like this:

```
{'12':'97.7,Car','11:99,Dog1}
```

and I would like to have it this way:

```
{'12':['97.8,Car','97.8 Car1','97.8,Car3'], 
 '11':['11,99,Dog1','11,99,Dog2']
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Can you explain how you choose the values? How did you end up in this situation, it seems odd, and really unfortunate. Could you also share your data? See: [mcve].

Comment: So in the first table, I have the second column which starts with 98.8, so I first want a filter to choose all the rows that have this same number. In this case I would get Car1 and Car2. In the only if I get those rows, however, when I update the dictionary, I only get Car1 and not Car2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by keeping a track of distinct values of seq_ids in the dict and then appending the data to particular seq_id. Check below:

```
table_1=open(name_table,'r')
results=[]
for seq_id in table_1:
    results.append(seq_id.strip().split('\t'))

data = dict()

for row in results:
    key = row[0]
    value = ','.join(row[1:])
    if row[0] not in data:
        data[key]=[]
    data[key].append(value)

print(data)
```

Comment: Yes this way I have the track of my values. However I don't want all the values in the  first table. So first I only want the numbers that share the same first number that appears in the second column, thats way I did the first if. So in this case I would only get Car1,Car2, but when I update the dictionary, I get only Car1.

Comment: The way I have described above will give you all the rows having same value of first column because based on that only the dict is being maintained. i.e. whenever it finds the same value of first column it appends other columns into previous result rather than replacing it. Please try running what I have described above and let me know if you don't get desired answer.